# In jQuery, using $.extend(), is this redundant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey, I was wondering if setting an object equal to $.extend(), but setting the target to the same object is redundant?

```
 setOptions(options = $.extend({
        classPrefix: 'imgareaselect',
        movable: true,
        resizable: true,
        parent: 'body',
        onInit: function () {},
        onSelectStart: function () {},
        onSelectChange: function () {},
        onSelectEnd: function () {}
    }, options));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way you've coded it, it's not redundant. That's because the *first* object passed in is the one that's modified, so all of the properties in `options` are being copied to the anonymous object you pass in as the first parameter. So you would then need to assign the return value of `$.extend` to something in order by be able to actually use it. If you'd done it the other way around:

```
$.extend(options, { ... });
```

Then the assignment *is* redundant. Note also that the order you pass objects in is important. By doing it the way you've done it, the anonymous object is basically the "defaults" and anything in `options` will override them.

Finally, because you're passing the result to a call to `setOptions` (which I assume saves the value somewhere) you also don't need an explicit assignment to `options`. But that depends entirely on what `setOptions` does and what you need `options` for later...